# What is the default working directory of a script run via launchd?

Tags: launchd

I'd expected this to be easy to find on Google, but wasn't able to discover anything.

I know that the working directory of a launchd agent/demon can be changed via the `workingdirectory` key. However, this key is optional. If no working directory is specified, what does macOS use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## TL;DR

The default value is `/`, as in

```xml
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/</string>
```

## Explanation

The `WorkingDirectory` in a *launchd* `.plist` is an optional *key* used to specify a directory to chdir(2) to before running the job. If this *key* is not present, then the *root* `/` directory is used.

I verified this by running a *shell script* as both a Launch Agent and a Launch Daemon that, when run, appended a directory listing to a text file. In all cases, without the `WorkingDirectory` *key*, the output was the *root*  `/` directory of the *startup disk*.

Depending on whether or not it was run as *root* or the *current user* the output as *root* also contained the hidden directories even though that was not explicitly set to output by the script.

As a side note, the `PATH` passed to the *shell script* when run as both a Launch Agent and Launch Daemon was:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Note that this was tested under OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Note for anyone stumbling across this answer in 2019: `/` is now read-only on macOS Catalina, so it may be worth setting `WorkingDirectory` to something like `/tmp` now, depending on what you need.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the $HOME of the $USER running the job?

Comment: @ardo82, RE: "Shouldn't it be the $HOME of the $USER running the job?" -- Shouldn't _what_ be? The default is `/` and if you want to change it, then set the `WorkingDirectory` _key_ to what you want it to be. Also, you have to use the actual _path_, not _variables_.